# How to add IP range to a server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ip

First of all I must say that I'm ver inexperienced server and network user. But I rented a unmanaged dedicated server. Well I didn't know what unmanaged really means, then I learned it when I needed support. Well I must do everything by myself.

I have a problem. I had already 4 IPs on my server when I rented it. But then I needed more Ips and my server assigned me 32 Ips in which I can only use 27 of them.

85.25.230.0 - 85.25.230.31 this is my Ip range and they say the following Ips must not be configured on the server:

85.25.230.0 - network address
85.25.230.1 - gateway address
85.25.230.2 - router redundancy
85.25.230.3 - router redundancy
85.25.230.31 - broadcast address

But the problem is ok Ips are assigned to me but they are not setup on my server. How will I setup Ips to work on my server?

I did this after my reseach on google:

I used this command on command prompt:

route add 85.25.230.0 mask 255.255.255.224 85.25.230.1 metric 1 if

then it said OK!. and I thought they should be working.

(btw, mask is given to me by my ISP and I don't know metric 1 and if means I just saw it on the net and write it here)

I setup my domains via using Plesk Kontrol Panel. So i added one domain and setup one of my new Ips 85.25.230.5 to it. But no it is not working. When I visit the domain via browser, there is a Plesk page comes and says this domain is not configured on the server.

Then I changed the domains Ip to one of my old Ips which are given to me with the server and which I have been using for my other domains for a long time. Ok in a second, domain started working. I set it back to my new Ip and domain did not work.

As I said, I'm not an expert and do not now the logic. But I'm eager to learn. Can you tell me what might couse the problem and did I do wrong while setting up IP RANGE to my server, if so how can I set them up?

Thank you,

Efe

Comment: ROUTE:
route add {destination network} mask {mask bits} {gateway} [metric] [metric number]

Answer (score 2):

You must also assign the IP address to a network card. On Linux, you can give a single card several IP addresses.

You didn't say which OS you're using, but [this article](http://linuxhelp.blogspot.com/2005/05/setting-up-multiple-ip-addresses-on.html) might help on Linux. [Here](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/multiipa.html) is the same for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation at Microsoft explains it. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771274.aspx  Doesn't seem to have changed much.  If you cannot access these dialogs, then you may not have permissions to change these settings.  A different problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a "range" of IPs to a server, but you can assign a lot of different IPs to a single server.  Adding more than one IP to a server is, under most scenarios, unnecessary unless you have a specific need.

Your routing rule;

```
route add 85.25.230.0 mask 255.255.255.224 85.25.230.1 metric 1 if
```

is unneccessary, and isn't doing what you think it will do. Since your network interface will set that up automatically, the routing rule is telling the server nothing new, what you're likely looking for is a rule to set up your default gateway.

```
route add -p 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 85.25.230.x metric y
```

where x is the gateway address, and metric is the gateway address times 10, this will set up three different routes to the internet which it will try in sequential order, should one gateway be unavailable.

You can also set up a single default gateway with simple windows ip configuration, through your network connections portion of the control panel.

if you don't add your gateway addresses, then the server will not be able to reach the internet.

Anyone else, please correct my routing rules if you see something wrong, I'm a little rusty, but i believe those should work.